# Powershell script to import, flatten and merge multiple xml files and export as csv

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

hello all you brave coders, I have a large amount of xml files that I need flattened, merged and converted to csv files for import into Excel, where the data will then be mapped to another dataset to be used in a larger data migration.

I have managed to produce a script that gathers all xml-files in a given folder and outputs the first level elements to a new row in a collected csv-file.
The problem is the structure of the xml files (which cannot be changed).
Here is a sample of the XML:

---

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<tmf_study_item>
  <a_acl_id type="String">0021AC7A0000000000081FDC</a_acl_id>
  <a_created_by type="String">xxxxxxxx</a_created_by>
  <ad_document_date type="LocalDate">2016-04-07</ad_document_date>
  <documents>
    <tmf_document>
      <a_acl_id type="String">0021AC7A00000000000823B1</a_acl_id>
      <a_acl_name type="String">TMF Study AC-064A201-Lupus Document Final ACL</a_acl_name>
      <a_modified_date type="Date">2016-04-19 05:28:06.708</a_modified_date>
      <multi_index_data>
        <multi_index_data>
          <amendment_number type="String"></amendment_number>
          <artifact_num type="String">01.05.03</artifact_num>
          <committee_type_code type="String"/>
        </multi_index_data>
      </multi_index_data>
      <related_placeholders>
      </related_placeholders>
      <shared_user>
      </shared_user>
      <workflow_user>
      </workflow_user>
      <contents>
        <content>
          <path>very_long_document_title1.pdf</path>
          <fileName>very_long_document_title1.pdf</fileName>
          <contentTypeId>pdf</contentTypeId>
          <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
        </content>
        <content>
          <path>very_long_document_title1.docx</path>
          <fileName>very_long_document_title1.docx</fileName>
          <contentTypeId>word_docx</contentTypeId>
          <mimeType>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</mimeType>
        </content>
      </contents>
    </tmf_document>
  </documents>
</tmf_study_item>
```

---

You will notice that some of the last elements occur twice an in some files there might be even more.
So what I need to know is how to flatten this xml hierarchy and provide the child-elements with unique names preferably in the form of 
    [parent.element]*[iteration]*[childelement]
while taking into account that the number of child-elements may vary and it should be exportable to csv.
Unique headers for childitems is necessary to do the mapping properly in excel afterward.

Here is the code I have written so far, what I rather clumsily try to do is process the 1st level elements first and then the "tmf_document" elements afterwards, joining them and then exporting to CSV. But for some reason I cannot figure out I get the error:
"Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name [basically all elements] because a member with that name already exists."
The code:

```
# Get all XML files
$rootElement = "tmf_study_item"
$documentElement = "tmf_document"
$midElement = "multi_index_data"
$items = Get-ChildItem *.xml
$scriptPath = $(get-location).Path
$scriptFolder = split-path $(get-location).Path -Leaf
$outputFile = $scriptPath+"\"+$scriptFolder+".csv"

# Loop through xmls and append them to the document
foreach ($item in $items) {
# Create filename for single CSV
$baseNameoutputFile = $scriptPath+"\"+(Get-ChildItem $item).BaseName+".csv"

[XML]$xml = (Get-Content $item) #load xml document
[Array]$RootitemConverted = $xml.GetElementsByTagName($rootElement)

# Create array for document elements
[Array]$DocConverted = $xml.GetElementsByTagName($documentElement)

# Create array for multi_index_data
[Array]$MidConverted = $xml.GetElementsByTagName($midElement)

$Collection = @()
Write-host "Start processing new XML >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"

# Loop over 1st level elements in XML------------------------------------------------------------
ForEach($Record in $RootitemConverted){

$Output = new-object psobject

$Record.selectnodes("*")|%{
Add-Member -InputObject $Output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.'#text'
}

Write-host "Add data to PSobject and collection >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"

If($Collection){
$T2Keys = $Collection|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
$T1Keys = $Output|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
$KeysToAdd = $T2Keys|?{$T1Keys -notcontains $_}
$KeysToAdd|%{$Collection|Add-Member $_ ""}
}

$Collection += $Output
}


# Loop over documents level elements in XML-----------------------------------------------------------------
ForEach($Documents in $DocConverted){

$DocOutput = new-object psobject
#Add Prefix to document-elements
$Documents.selectnodes("*")|%{
$tmpName = $_.Name
$tmpName = $documentElement+"_1_"+$tmpName
Write-Host $tmpName
Add-Member -InputObject $DocOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $tmpName -Value $_.'#text'
}

Write-host "Add data to PSobject and collection >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"

If($Collection){
$T2Keys = $Collection|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
$T1Keys = $DocOutput|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
$KeysToAdd = $T2Keys|?{$T1Keys -notcontains $_}
$KeysToAdd|%{$Collection|Add-Member $_ ""}
}

$Collection += $DocOutput
}

$Collection

# Append to CSV File
$Collection | Export-Csv -path $outputFile -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Append

# Create a CSV for each file
#$Collection | Export-Csv -path $baseNameoutputFile -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I hope some of you can give me some pointers on how to solve this.

Comment: In stepping through your code and example file, I was able to arbitrarily add to the collection variable with this:
`$Collection|Add-Member $("someName"+"_1_"+$_) -NotePropertyValue $_`

You could create a counter variable and tick it up everytime you go through your collection with all the values you want to add so that the static "1" in my example above would dynamically change each iteration

Is that what you're after here?

Comment: hi t, I cannot get your code to work.
What I need is basically to flatten the structure of the imported xml in a way that will provide unique and individual fields in the output csv. Since some of the child elements share the same name as some of the parent elements I thought it would be best to rename the child-elements  so that they are prefixed with the parent element names.
In my script I managed to process the 1st level elements and then the child elements separately, but I can't join them. Maybe processing them separately is not the best way to go about this at all.

Comment: I tried another approach add members to two different collections, one for each xml level and then joining them. The joining part works now, but it doesn't look like they are merged correctly and the last collection in not visible in the csv at all.